# How to index multiple versions of a word in sphinxsearch

Tags: search, full-text-search, search-engine, sphinx

I am having a problem with sphinxsearch.

I am using metaphone morphology to make search abit more fuzzy and autocorrect typical typos. It works for most parts, but in case where there are 2 similary sounding words, searching for the exact one is not possible.

eg. "Poul" and "Bowl" both give morphology result of "PL", becouse of that they both give the same resultset (that is ok) and order (that is bad).

Is there any way of having multiple different morphlogies used in indexing, so that I could use them for scoring?

Results that I expect is to have an index of sentence "It is a big bowl" contain both raw "bowl" word as well as morphologied "PL", so searching for word "bowl" will give it higher score than searching for word "Poul".

edit:
I added my current config file

```
source base_src
{
    type                    = mysql
    sql_host                = 127.0.0.1
    sql_port                = 3306
    sql_db                  = <hidden>
    sql_user                = <hidden>
    sql_pass                = <hidden>
    sql_query_pre           = SET NAMES utf8
    sql_query_pre           = SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=utf8
}


index base
{
    docinfo         = extern
    min_infix_len   = 2
    min_word_len    = 2
    ignore_chars    = U+0027
    html_strip      = 1
    blend_mode      = trim_head, trim_tail
    charset_table   = 0..9, a..z, _, A..Z->a..z, U+00C0->a, U+00C1->a,\
            U+00C2->a, U+00C3->a, U+00C4->a, U+00C5->a, U+00C7->c, U+00C8->e,\
            U+00C9->e, U+00CA->e, U+00CB->e, U+00CC->i, U+00CD->i, U+00CE->i,\
            U+00CF->i, U+00D1->n, U+00D2->o, U+00D3->o, U+00D4->o, U+00D5->o,\
            U+00D6->o, U+00D8->o, U+00D9->u, U+00DA->u, U+00DB->u, U+00DC->u,\
            U+00DD->y, U+00DF->s, U+00E0->a, U+00E1->a, U+00E2->a, U+00E3->a,\
            U+00E4->a, U+00E5->a, U+00E7->c, U+00E8->e, U+00E9->e, U+00EA->e,\
            U+00EB->e, U+00EC->i, U+00ED->i, U+00EE->i, U+00EF->i, U+00F1->n,\
            U+00F2->o, U+00F3->o, U+00F4->o, U+00F5->o, U+00F6->o, U+00F8->o,\
            U+00F9->u, U+00FA->u, U+00FB->u, U+00FC->u, U+00FD->y, U+00FF->y,\
            U+0100->a, U+0101->a, U+0102->a, U+0103->a, U+0104->a, U+0105->a,\
            U+0106->c, U+0107->c, U+0108->c, U+0109->c, U+010A->c, U+010B->c,\
            U+010C->c, U+010D->c, U+010E->d, U+010F->d, U+0110->d, U+0111->d,\
            U+0112->e, U+0113->e, U+0114->e, U+0115->e, U+0116->e, U+0117->e,\
            U+0118->e, U+0119->e, U+011A->e, U+011B->e, U+011C->g, U+011D->g,\
            U+011E->g, U+011F->g, U+0120->g, U+0121->g, U+0122->g, U+0123->g,\
            U+0124->h, U+0125->h, U+0126->h, U+0127->h, U+0128->i, U+0129->i,\
            U+012A->i, U+012B->i, U+012C->i, U+012D->i, U+012E->i, U+012F->i,\
            U+0130->i, U+0131->i, U+0134->j, U+0135->j, U+0136->k, U+0137->k,\
            U+0139->l, U+013A->l, U+013B->l, U+013C->l, U+013D->l, U+013E->l,\
            U+013F->l, U+0140->l, U+0141->l, U+0142->l, U+0143->n, U+0144->n,\
            U+0145->n, U+0146->n, U+0147->n, U+0148->n, U+0149->n, U+014C->o,\
            U+014D->o, U+014E->o, U+014F->o, U+0150->o, U+0151->o, U+0154->r,\
            U+0155->r, U+0156->r, U+0157->r, U+0158->r, U+0159->r, U+015A->s,\
            U+015B->s, U+015C->s, U+015D->s, U+015E->s, U+015F->s, U+0160->s,\
            U+0161->s, U+0162->t, U+0163->t, U+0164->t, U+0165->t, U+0166->t,\
            U+0167->t, U+0168->u, U+0169->u, U+016A->u, U+016B->u, U+016C->u,\
            U+016D->u, U+016E->u, U+016F->u, U+0170->u, U+0171->u, U+0172->u,\
            U+0173->u, U+0174->w, U+0175->w, U+0176->y, U+0177->y, U+0178->y,\
            U+0179->z, U+017A->z, U+017B->z, U+017C->z, U+017D->z, U+017E->z,\
            U+017F->s, U+0180->b, U+0181->b, U+0182->b, U+0183->b, U+0186->o,\
            U+0187->c, U+0188->c, U+0189->d, U+018A->d, U+018B->d, U+018C->d,\
            U+018E->e, U+0190->e, U+0191->f, U+0192->f, U+0193->g, U+0197->i,\
            U+0198->k, U+0199->k, U+019A->l, U+019C->m, U+019D->n, U+019E->n,\
            U+019F->o, U+01A0->o, U+01A1->o, U+01A4->p, U+01A5->p, U+01AB->t,\
            U+01AC->t, U+01AD->t, U+01AE->t, U+01AF->u, U+01B0->u, U+01B2->v,\
            U+01B3->y, U+01B4->y, U+01B5->z, U+01B6->z, U+01C5->d, U+01C8->j,\
            U+01C8->l, U+01CB->j, U+01CB->n, U+01CD->a, U+01CE->a, U+01CF->i,\
            U+01D0->i, U+01D1->o, U+01D2->o, U+01D3->u, U+01D4->u, U+01D5->u,\
            U+01D6->u, U+01D7->u, U+01D8->u, U+01D9->u, U+01DA->u, U+01DB->u,\
            U+01DC->u, U+01DD->e, U+01DE->a, U+01DF->a, U+01E0->a, U+01E1->a,\
            U+01E4->g, U+01E5->g, U+01E6->g, U+01E7->g, U+01E8->k, U+01E9->k,\
            U+01EA->o, U+01EB->o, U+01EC->o, U+01ED->o, U+01F0->j, U+01F2->d,\
            U+01F4->g, U+01F5->g, U+01F8->n, U+01F9->n, U+01FA->a, U+01FB->a,\
            U+01FE->o, U+01FF->o, U+0200->a, U+0201->a, U+0202->a, U+0203->a,\
            U+0204->e, U+0205->e, U+0206->e, U+0207->e, U+0208->i, U+0209->i,\
            U+020A->i, U+020B->i, U+020C->o, U+020D->o, U+020E->o, U+020F->o,\
            U+0210->r, U+0211->r, U+0212->r, U+0213->r, U+0214->u, U+0215->u,\
            U+0216->u, U+0217->u, U+0218->s, U+0219->s, U+021A->t, U+021B->t,\
            U+021E->h, U+021F->h, U+0220->n, U+0221->d, U+0224->z, U+0225->z,\
            U+0226->a, U+0227->a, U+0228->e, U+0229->e, U+022A->o, U+022B->o,\
            U+022C->o, U+022D->o, U+022E->o, U+022F->o, U+0230->o, U+0231->o,\
            U+0232->y, U+0233->y, U+0234->l, U+0235->n, U+0236->t, U+0237->j,\
            U+023A->a, U+023B->c, U+023C->c, U+023D->l, U+023E->t, U+023F->s,\
            U+0240->z, U+0243->b, U+0244->u, U+0245->v, U+0246->e, U+0247->e,\
            U+0248->j, U+0249->j, U+024A->q, U+024B->q, U+024C->r, U+024D->r,\
            U+024E->y, U+024F->y, U+0250->a, U+0253->b, U+0254->o, U+0255->c,\
            U+0256->d, U+0257->d, U+0258->e, U+025B->e, U+025C->e, U+025D->e,\
            U+025E->e, U+025F->j, U+0260->g, U+0261->g, U+0262->g, U+0265->h,\
            U+0266->h, U+0268->i, U+026A->i, U+026B->l, U+026C->l, U+026D->l,\
            U+026F->m, U+0270->m, U+0271->m, U+0272->n, U+0273->n, U+0274->n,\
            U+0275->o, U+0279->r, U+027A->r, U+027B->r, U+027C->r, U+027D->r,\
            U+027E->r, U+027F->r, U+0280->r, U+0281->r, U+0282->s, U+0284->j,\
            U+0287->t, U+0288->t, U+0289->u, U+028B->v, U+028C->v, U+028D->w,\
            U+028E->y, U+028F->y, U+0290->z, U+0291->z, U+0297->c, U+0299->b,\
            U+029A->e, U+029B->g, U+029C->h, U+029D->j, U+029E->k, U+029F->l,\
            U+02A0->q, U+02AE->h, U+02AF->h, U+02B0->h, U+02B1->h, U+02B2->j,\
            U+02B3->r, U+02B4->r, U+02B5->r, U+02B6->r, U+02B7->w, U+02B8->y,\
            U+02E1->l, U+02E2->s, U+02E3->x, U+040D->i, U+0418->i, U+0419->i,\
            U+0438->i, U+0439->i, U+043E->o, U+0456->i, U+04D0->a, U+04D1->a,\
            U+04E6->o, U+04E7->o, U+04E8->o, U+04E9->o, U+04EA->o, U+04EB->o,\
            U+16D2->b, U+1D03->b, U+1D05->d, U+1D07->e, U+1D08->e, U+1D09->i,\
            U+1D0A->j, U+1D0B->k, U+1D0C->l, U+1D0D->m, U+1D0E->n, U+1D0F->o,\
            U+1D10->o, U+1D11->o, U+1D12->o, U+1D13->o, U+1D16->o, U+1D17->o,\
            U+1D18->p, U+1D19->r, U+1D1A->r, U+1D1B->t, U+1D1C->u, U+1D1D->u,\
            U+1D1E->u, U+1D1F->m, U+1D20->v, U+1D21->w, U+1D22->z, U+1D2C->a,\
            U+1D2E->b, U+1D2F->b, U+1D30->d, U+1D31->e, U+1D32->e, U+1D33->g,\
            U+1D34->h, U+1D35->i, U+1D36->j, U+1D37->k, U+1D38->l, U+1D39->m,\
            U+1D3A->n, U+1D3B->n, U+1D3C->o, U+1D3E->p, U+1D3F->r, U+1D40->t,\
            U+1D41->u, U+1D42->w, U+1D43->a, U+1D44->a, U+1D47->b, U+1D48->d,\
            U+1D49->e, U+1D4B->e, U+1D4C->e, U+1D4D->g, U+1D4E->i, U+1D4F->k,\
            U+1D50->m, U+1D52->o, U+1D53->o, U+1D54->o, U+1D55->o, U+1D56->p,\
            U+1D57->t, U+1D58->u, U+1D59->u, U+1D5A->m, U+1D5B->v, U+1D62->i,\
            U+1D63->r, U+1D64->u, U+1D65->v, U+1D6C->b, U+1D6D->d, U+1D6E->f,\
            U+1D6F->m, U+1D70->n, U+1D71->p, U+1D72->r, U+1D73->r, U+1D74->s,\
            U+1D75->t, U+1D76->z, U+1D77->g, U+1D79->g, U+1D7B->i, U+1D7D->p,\
            U+1D7E->u, U+1D80->b, U+1D81->d, U+1D82->f, U+1D83->g, U+1D84->k,\
            U+1D85->l, U+1D86->m, U+1D87->n, U+1D88->p, U+1D89->r, U+1D8A->s,\
            U+1D8C->v, U+1D8D->x, U+1D8E->z, U+1D8F->a, U+1D91->d, U+1D92->e,\
            U+1D93->e, U+1D94->e, U+1D96->i, U+1D97->o, U+1D99->u, U+1D9C->c,\
            U+1D9D->c, U+1D9F->e, U+1DA0->f, U+1DA1->j, U+1DA2->g, U+1DA3->h,\
            U+1DA4->i, U+1DA6->i, U+1DA7->i, U+1DA8->j, U+1DA9->l, U+1DAA->l,\
            U+1DAB->l, U+1DAC->m, U+1DAD->m, U+1DAE->n, U+1DAF->n, U+1DB0->n,\
            U+1DB1->o, U+1DB3->s, U+1DB5->t, U+1DB6->u, U+1DB8->u, U+1DB9->v,\
            U+1DBA->v, U+1DBB->z, U+1DBC->z, U+1DBD->z, U+1DCA->r, U+1E00->a,\
            U+1E01->a, U+1E02->b, U+1E03->b, U+1E04->b, U+1E05->b, U+1E06->b,\
            U+1E07->b, U+1E08->c, U+1E09->c, U+1E0A->d, U+1E0B->d, U+1E0C->d,\
            U+1E0D->d, U+1E0E->d, U+1E0F->d, U+1E10->d, U+1E11->d, U+1E12->d,\
            U+1E13->d, U+1E14->e, U+1E15->e, U+1E16->e, U+1E17->e, U+1E18->e,\
            U+1E19->e, U+1E1A->e, U+1E1B->e, U+1E1C->e, U+1E1D->e, U+1E1E->f,\
            U+1E1F->f, U+1E20->g, U+1E21->g, U+1E22->h, U+1E23->h, U+1E24->h,\
            U+1E25->h, U+1E26->h, U+1E27->h, U+1E28->h, U+1E29->h, U+1E2A->h,\
            U+1E2B->h, U+1E2C->i, U+1E2D->i, U+1E2E->i, U+1E2F->i, U+1E30->k,\
            U+1E31->k, U+1E32->k, U+1E33->k, U+1E34->k, U+1E35->k, U+1E36->l,\
            U+1E37->l, U+1E38->l, U+1E39->l, U+1E3A->l, U+1E3B->l, U+1E3C->l,\
            U+1E3D->l, U+1E3E->m, U+1E3F->m, U+1E40->m, U+1E41->m, U+1E42->m,\
            U+1E43->m, U+1E44->n, U+1E45->n, U+1E46->n, U+1E47->n, U+1E48->n,\
            U+1E49->n, U+1E4A->n, U+1E4B->n, U+1E4C->o, U+1E4D->o, U+1E4E->o,\
            U+1E4F->o, U+1E50->o, U+1E51->o, U+1E52->o, U+1E53->o, U+1E54->p,\
            U+1E55->p, U+1E56->p, U+1E57->p, U+1E58->r, U+1E59->r, U+1E5A->r,\
            U+1E5B->r, U+1E5C->r, U+1E5D->r, U+1E5E->r, U+1E5F->r, U+1E60->s,\
            U+1E61->s, U+1E62->s, U+1E63->s, U+1E64->s, U+1E65->s, U+1E66->s,\
            U+1E67->s, U+1E68->s, U+1E69->s, U+1E6A->t, U+1E6B->t, U+1E6C->t,\
            U+1E6D->t, U+1E6E->t, U+1E6F->t, U+1E70->t, U+1E71->t, U+1E72->u,\
            U+1E73->u, U+1E74->u, U+1E75->u, U+1E76->u, U+1E77->u, U+1E78->u,\
            U+1E79->u, U+1E7A->u, U+1E7B->u, U+1E7C->v, U+1E7D->v, U+1E7E->v,\
            U+1E7F->v, U+1E80->w, U+1E81->w, U+1E82->w, U+1E83->w, U+1E84->w,\
            U+1E85->w, U+1E86->w, U+1E87->w, U+1E88->w, U+1E89->w, U+1E8A->x,\
            U+1E8B->x, U+1E8C->x, U+1E8D->x, U+1E8E->y, U+1E8F->y, U+1E90->z,\
            U+1E91->z, U+1E92->z, U+1E93->z, U+1E94->z, U+1E95->z, U+1E96->h,\
            U+1E97->t, U+1E98->w, U+1E99->y, U+1E9A->a, U+1E9B->s, U+1EA0->a,\
            U+1EA1->a, U+1EA2->a, U+1EA3->a, U+1EA4->a, U+1EA5->a, U+1EA6->a,\
            U+1EA7->a, U+1EA8->a, U+1EA9->a, U+1EAA->a, U+1EAB->a, U+1EAC->a,\
            U+1EAD->a, U+1EAE->a, U+1EAF->a, U+1EB0->a, U+1EB1->a, U+1EB2->a,\
            U+1EB3->a, U+1EB4->a, U+1EB5->a, U+1EB6->a, U+1EB7->a, U+1EB8->e,\
            U+1EB9->e, U+1EBA->e, U+1EBB->e, U+1EBC->e, U+1EBD->e, U+1EBE->e,\
            U+1EBF->e, U+1EC0->e, U+1EC1->e, U+1EC2->e, U+1EC3->e, U+1EC4->e,\
            U+1EC5->e, U+1EC6->e, U+1EC7->e, U+1EC8->i, U+1EC9->i, U+1ECA->i,\
            U+1ECB->i, U+1ECC->o, U+1ECD->o, U+1ECE->o, U+1ECF->o, U+1ED0->o,\
            U+1ED1->o, U+1ED2->o, U+1ED3->o, U+1ED4->o, U+1ED5->o, U+1ED6->o,\
            U+1ED7->o, U+1ED8->o, U+1ED9->o, U+1EDA->o, U+1EDB->o, U+1EDC->o,\
            U+1EDD->o, U+1EDE->o, U+1EDF->o, U+1EE0->o, U+1EE1->o, U+1EE2->o,\
            U+1EE3->o, U+1EE4->u, U+1EE5->u, U+1EE6->u, U+1EE7->u, U+1EE8->u,\
            U+1EE9->u, U+1EEA->u, U+1EEB->u, U+1EEC->u, U+1EED->u, U+1EEE->u,\
            U+1EEF->u, U+1EF0->u, U+1EF1->u, U+1EF2->y, U+1EF3->y, U+1EF4->y,\
            U+1EF5->y, U+1EF6->y, U+1EF7->y, U+1EF8->y, U+1EF9->y, U+2071->i,\
            U+207F->n, U+2090->a, U+2091->e, U+2092->o, U+2093->x, U+210C->h,\
            U+2111->i, U+211C->r, U+2128->z, U+212D->c, U+2184->c, U+2C60->l,\
            U+2C61->l, U+2C62->l, U+2C63->p, U+2C64->r, U+2C65->a, U+2C66->t,\
            U+2C67->h, U+2C68->h, U+2C69->k, U+2C6A->k, U+2C6B->z, U+2C6C->z,\
            U+2C74->v, U+2C75->h, U+2C76->h, U+2C9E->o, U+2C9F->o, U+10300->a,\
            U+10309->i, U+1030F->o, U+10316->u
    blend_chars     = U+0040
}


source products_src : base_src
{
    sql_query = \
        SELECT \
            p.id, \
            p.name, \
            p.designer, \
            p.description, \
        FROM products p \
        WHERE \
            p.status = 'Active';

    sql_field_string     = name
    sql_field_string     = designer
    sql_field_string     = description
}

index products : base
{
    dict            = keywords
    index_exact_words = 1
    expand_keywords = 1
    morphology      = metaphone
    source          = products_src
    path            = /var/lib/sphinxsearch/data/products
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `index_exact_words` : http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-index-exact-words

... along with `expand_keywords` :http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-expand-keywords

> Expanded queries take naturally longer to complete, but can possibly improve the search quality, as the documents with exact form matches should be ranked generally higher than documents with stemmed <s>or infix matches</s>.

(in your case stemming is actully metaphone - because its really morphology )

Comment: I am already using those. I added my current config file (the important parts) to the question. Also, from what I see the exact match is only concidered for entire field. When I experimented with different rankers I found that even for products that contain word "bowl" the "exact match" was equal to 0.

Comment: how are you ordering results? Maybe sphinx can caculate a 'weight' to sort the results, but you ignoring it?

Comment: I am not ordering explicitly (I use the default)
I also show the weight for debugging purpose, and its ordered from highest to lowest (At least first page / 20 items are)

Also based on my experimenting I found that when I use proximity ranker then all results have exactly the same weight.

Comment: The promitiyt ranker is very basic, it wont really be affected by expand keywords. try wordcount, its also basic, but should use it as a demo.